# copy variable by value not reference

Tags: python, variables, reference, copy

quite new to python and struggling to achieve a value copy of a variable. have an algorithm that calls recursively another one but not getting the desired values since i think im instead using reference when assigning one variable to another in the following code:

```
def search(problem, strategy, depthl, depthi, pruning):
    depthact = depthi
    sol = None
    while(not sol and depthact <= depthl):
        sol = limSearch(problem, strategy, depthact, pruning)
        depthact += depthi
    return sol
```

i want to have in **depthact** the same value as **depthi** but instead i think im pointing to the same memory location and therefore when calling *limSearch* im doing it with whatever value is passed to the method in *depthi* instead of the other one that is the one i wanna use since i then increment it.

am i right? any help will be much appreciated.

**edit:** i know the solution to the limSearch algoritm is in a depth=35 but want this other algorithm to check if a solution exits for a given depth increment so, if i call search with depthl=40 and a depthi of 2, it should run limSearch passing in depthact the value 2 at first, then 4, 6, 8, 10.. until it reaches 36 that then it should find the solution cause of it being in 35 but it does not work, instead im getting a sol=None in all cases as if i was calling limSearch with other values.

> def search(problem, strategy, 40, 2, pruning):

i want a call like this one to be in the loop calling limSearch until it reaches a solution in that algorithm that in this case is in depth=35. so my expected result is:

> sol = limSearch(problem, strategy, 2, pruning)
>
> sol = limSearch(problem, strategy, 4, pruning)
>
> sol = limSearch(problem, strategy, 6, pruning)

...

> sol = limSearch(problem, strategy, 36, pruning)

in this last iteration sol will not be none and then the while loop will no longer be executed returning me the desired solution.

the context where i call this function is the following:

```
if(strategy == 3): sol = search(p, strategy, depthl, depthi, pruning)
else: sol = limSearch(p, strategy, depthl, pruning)
```

after reading all the values values by user inputs.

```
depthl = int(input('depth: '))-1
if(strategy == 3): depthi = int(input('depth increment: '))
```

Answer (score 6):

Generally, if you have concerns with references and copying data, the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html) is going to give you the fine-grained copy control you're looking for.

`copy.copy` is guaranteed to do a "shallow copy", where a list will contain references to the old data, but will be a new list (or other container).

`copy.deepcopy` will give you a "deep copy" where the elements themselves will be copied.

In this case though, you have a simple type `int` and is immutable, therefore a new instance is created whenever the value is changed.  (It's a bit more complicated than that with immutable objects, but the point is that if you're using simple types than the assignment operator `=` will not modify other instances of those symple types that you've assigned.)

ie:

```
a = 42
b = a
b +=1
print(a)
print(b)
```

This prints "42" and "43" showing that modifying b will not modify a.

If you're not copying a generic type than you should copy module.  Arbitrary classes can implement methods `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` ([more info](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#copying)) to make copies of object and is the most pythonic way to ensure that copies are made the way that users expect.

Edit:
To those that would edit posts to remove the first person voice of my response; do not do that.  I an answering the OP and not writing a technical journal, and *readability counts*.  I accept that my answer was incorrect, but only in that I suggested the use of the `int` type constructor when it was not necessary (although the result would have been the same, it was not *pythonic*).  And I've included the bit about immutable data types here, but I do not feel that saying that "`int` is immutable" is a sufficient answer because being *explicit is better than implicit*.  Having said that, knowledge of immutable types and the standard library `copy` module is probably the most complete response.

Comment: In what circumstance would making a copy of an integer ever make a difference except when doing identity checks with `is`, which isn't being used here?

Comment: And even then, `is` is fallible due to cached integers in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an int or a float or something like that, you can always try casting the value to a string and then back to the original type:

```
a = 20
b = int(f"{a}")

print(a, b)
a = 8181
print(a, b)
a = 1111
b = 123
print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
20   20
8181 20
1111 123
```

Another method to support additional values, and arguably the simplest, is to write a function that just returns the value:

```
def copy_value(value_to_copy):
    return value_to_copy
```